TIA Portal: Current Setpoint line not showing on graph using Compact PID
I just made a PID controller in TIA portal to simulate a water tank in factory IO. When I open the PID Compact settings to tune the controller and press start I can change the setpoint value that shows below "Online status of controller" with a potentiometer in Factory IO, but the trendline on the graph shows 0.
enter image description here
I am using TIA portal v15 and using the template for the S7-1200 that is available in the factory IO site
I made a quick look to see if all the tags are addressed correctly and also displayed the setpoint potentiometer's value on a digital display to see if there was a communication error
